# Spring Security Account lockout

Tags: spring-security

hi I have a j2ee application using Spring webflow and Spring Security. I want to implement an account lockout such that after three times of password failure the account wil be locked. How do I implement this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use an [AuthenticationFailureHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.html)? This approach was suggested in the [Acegi FAQ](http://web.archive.org/web/20100225101935/http://www.acegisecurity.org/faq.html) (see Common Problem #3).

Comment: I registered a bean implementing the application handler and checking for an instance of AuthenticationFailureHandler

Answer (score 1):

That behavior belongs to the underline authentication provider. If you are using LDAP there is a Password Policy, the [LdapAuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.html) will throw an exception if the account is blocked.
If your current [AuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) doesn't have this functionality then subclass it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AuthenticationFailureHandler**

```
public class MySimpleAuthenticationFailureHandler  implements
AuthenticationFailureHandler {

private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

 public MySimpleAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        super();
    }
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

    String message = "";

    if(exception instanceof UsernameNotFoundException) {
        message = "UsernameNotFoundException";
    } else if(exception instanceof AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException) {
        message = "AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException";
    }else if(exception instanceof InsufficientAuthenticationException) {
        message = "InsufficientAuthenticationException";
    }else if(exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
        message = "AccountExpiredException";
    }else if(exception instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
        message = "CredentialsExpiredException";
    }else if(exception instanceof DisabledException) {
        message = "DisabledException";
    }else if(exception instanceof LockedException) {
        message = "LockedException";
    }else if(exception instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
        message = "BadCredentialsException";
    }else{
        message = exception.getMessage();
    }
    final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("errorMessage", message);
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/login?error="+message);
}

}
```