# Locking account after multiple failures in Spring-Oauth2 Password Grant Type

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Is it possible to lock an account after say 3 consecutive failures? The login attempt is facilitated using the (Spring) Oauth Password flow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137186/spring-security-account-lockout  You'll have to keep a session counter.

Comment: @ElGuapo that would not work. The AuthenticationFailureHandler, only works for Form Login. In my case it's happening using Spring-Oauth password flow (no form login).

Comment: Sorry... well, my suggestion would be to use eclipse or netbeans (or your favorite editor) to debug the security process and see what you can see... I've found that to be the best when using Spring Security